# Distinct cumulative Count with date restriction in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sales dataframe like this:

```
data = {
    'client_id': ['01419', '1444', '346344', '83204', '8370660'],
    'order_date': ['2022-04-06', '2021-05-22', '2022-11-10', '2023-02-22', '2019-06-11'],
    'order_id': [200140, 146977, 249517, 260853, 91743],
    'name': ['TACIANA', 'ROSANA', 'MARIA', 'ERIVAL', 'JOAO']
         
}
```

i need to create a new column that distinct counts for each row the client_id's which have made a purchase in the last 720 days. So the output dataframe would be like this

```
df2 = {
'client_id': ['01419', '1444', '346344', '83204', '8370660'],
'order_date': ['2022-04-06', '2021-05-22', '2022-11-10', '2023-02-22', '2019-06-11'],
'order_id': [200140, 146977, 249517, 260853, 91743],
'name': ['TACIANA', 'ROSANA', 'MARIA', 'ERIVAL', 'JOAO'],
'active_base': [1, 1, 2, 3, 0]
        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'client_id': ['01419', '1444', '346344', '83204', '8370660'],
    'order_date': ['2022-04-06', '2021-05-22', '2022-11-10', '2023-02-22', '2019-06-11'],
    'order_id': [200140, 146977, 249517, 260853, 91743],
    'name': ['TACIANA', 'ROSANA', 'MARIA', 'ERIVAL', 'JOAO']

}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])
df['last_date'] = df['order_date'] - datetime.timedelta(days=720)
df['active_base'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.count_nonzero((df['order_date'] < x['order_date']) & (df['order_date'] > x['last_date'])), axis=1)
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  client_id order_date  order_id     name  last_date  active_base
0     01419 2022-04-06    200140  TACIANA 2020-04-16            1
1      1444 2021-05-22    146977   ROSANA 2019-06-02            1
2    346344 2022-11-10    249517    MARIA 2020-11-20            2
3     83204 2023-02-22    260853   ERIVAL 2021-03-04            3
4   8370660 2019-06-11     91743     JOAO 2017-06-21            0
```

Comment: The client_id 8370660 has no order before him, so if the condition is to count all the client_id's which has orders until 720 days before the order_date column, the result will be 0, because there is no order before 2019.

Comment: I updated my answer. I thing it now fits the requirements.